# C#: How to wake up system which has been shutdown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, acpi, winapi

Is there any Win32 API for waking up a system that has been shut down, at a specific time? I have seen a program named Autopower On which is able to power the system on at a specified time.

Comment: When would you run this C# program? While the computer is off? Or before it is turned off?

Comment: i run this program before it is turned off.

Comment: You need to dig into ACPI.  A bit of googling says you can access this with WMI, but I'm not sure to what extent.

Comment: @Brad: what should i google for ? tell me some keywords to search.

Comment: The Auto Power-on program (http://lifsoft.com/) does not work when a computer has been shut down. It only works on sleeping/hibernating computers.

Comment: @vishnu, I already told you in my comment... .NET and ACPI but it looks like you were able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got [the below post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31842595/-simulate-wake-up-computer-to-run-this-task-feature-of-task-scheduler-in-c.aspx) from a site. Any body tried this?

Nothing in the framework, so you'll have to "PInvoke" a bit.
The API's you need to call are CreateWaitableTimer and SetWaitableTimer.
Following is a complete (Q&D) sample that illustrates how you can set a
system to be awoken from sleep/hibernate using above Win32 API's.
Note that here I'm setting a relative wakeup time of 300000000 nSecs.
That means that the computer will wake-up (supposing he's asleep or
hibernating) within 30 seconds after setting the timer.
Consult the MSDN docs for details on SetWaitableTimer and it's arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Willys
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes,
        bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(IntPtr hTimer, [In] ref long
        pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr
        lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, uint
        milliseconds);

        static void Main()
        {
            SetWaitForWakeUpTime();
        }

        static IntPtr handle;
        static void SetWaitForWakeUpTime()
        {
            long duetime = -300000000; // negative value, so a RELATIVE due time
            Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", duetime);
            handle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, true, "MyWaitabletimer");
            SetWaitableTimer(handle, ref duetime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
            uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            int ret = WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
            MessageBox.Show("Wake up call");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the program so it works. I've verified that it wakes my computer up from sleep and hibernation. I don't expect it to wake up from being shutdown, however.

Comment: I have tried this code on windows 8 desktop and tablet but it doesnt work. Does it have to do something with my device supporting this feature or all devices would support the wake up option? I had a look at the Allow wake timers option under the sleep option in advanced power settings but changing that too on desktop dint work and tablet dint have the option at all

Comment: On that site there were caveats that you also need to ensure you don't require a password to be entered to wake it/on wake, and in the Sleep settings, to Allow Wake Timers.

Answer (score 2):

This [Wake on LAN (WOL)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/WOL.aspx) code project post might be of use (Both motherboard and NIC must support WOL)

Answer (score 2):

Once you actually shut down your computer(not sleeping or hibernating) you can't wake it up from C#, C++ code directly. After all the OS itself is closed.

The only chance would be for your motherboard to support some kind of timer mechanism. And with some C++ function to be able to write some flags into the BIOS and set that timer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the windows "Scheduled Task" menu. See:

http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/

You create a program that you want to run upon wake up and then manually enter it into the windows scheduled task list for the first time to wake after a specific time.

When you program awakens, I am not sure if you need your program to call a Windows API to 
stop it being awoken again, ditto if you want your program to power off the PC after starting another sceduled task to awaken it again. Need to reserach what windows APIs there are for this.

Comment: This is a non-programming answer which would be suitable for SuperUser.  It doesn't answer the programming question which was asked, though, which requires configuring the wakeup from C#.