# How do I set the wake up time to system before shutdown the PC?

Tags: c#-4.0, intel

I am new in C#, I am developing the project at C#.net windows application in that I need to read the next schedule time from my schedule file, if there is no schedule for next one hour, my system need not to wake on until next schedule time reach which is defined in schedule file. My system needs to shutdown, and before shutdown it need to set the timer for system wake. How to set the system on time before shutdown my pc.
I did this same in Linux system through python script by writing the system on time at `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealaram`location. I just write the next system on time at this location and shutdown the system, the system can be automatically on by reach the time which is given in `wakealaram` file. I need to do the same in Windows system by using C#.

Comment: There is a related [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49798/Wake-the-PC-from-standby-or-hibernation) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to wake up system which has been shutdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061844/c-how-to-wake-up-system-which-has-been-shutdown)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at below.

```
#region Clock Reset
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        public short Year;
        public short Month;
        public short DayOfWeek;
        public short Day;
        public short Hour;
        public short Minute;
        public short Second;
        public short Milliseconds;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

    private void ResetSystemTime(DateTime tdt)
    {
        try
        {

            SYSTEMTIME time = new SYSTEMTIME();
            time.Day = (short)tdt.Day;
            time.Month = (short)tdt.Month;
            time.Year = (short)tdt.Year;
            time.Hour = (short)tdt.Hour;
            time.Minute = (short)tdt.Minute;
            time.Second = (short)tdt.Second;
            SetSystemTime(ref time);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("System time reset Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for the edit.. the "hash" commented out everything

Comment: Your code just sets the [system time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). How does this relate to a wake up time?

Comment: I am not sure about sleep/wake up settings of OS. I am only familiar with working with System Time. Also, to make sure the System Time sticks, internet time adjustment should be turned off.

Comment: dude, expect anyone reply answer for this question.